# How to make a launcher for activate Wifi

Tags: command-line, networking, drivers, launcher, ralink

I have a problem that after every update, because of my Ralink Wifi-Board, the WLAN is not activated and I have to run these commands to make it work again:

```
cd /home/makkekkazzo/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt5390sta
sudo ifconfig enp2s0 up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

For this reason I want to know if it is possible to  make a script with only these commands that will run after every update automatically by clicking on it.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi makkekkazzo, could you mention if all is clear?

Comment: Hi Jacob, it seems that I managed to make the launcher and it seems working, but now I have to wait till next update to look if it works the way we expect. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: Ah, great. If you are updating, please let me know if it works. If not for whatever reason, I am sure we can fix.

Comment: So Jacob I can assure you that your launcher works fine. The first time I saved it in /bin/ and wasn't working but now I made it in Documents and is every fine. The only thing that I've know discovered is that probably the problem has not to due with update but with restarting the computer (I had the problem before because most of the time I was restarting after updates), because after creating your launcher I restarted and the network wasn't there.

Comment: Ah,  I believe asking a new question would likely trigger more network- oriented specialists here. Thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most convenient (and flexible) is to create a script for it:

1. First install gksu:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gksu
   ```
2. Then create the script:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash

   cd /home/makkekkazzo/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/
   make
   make install
   modprobe rt5390sta
   ifconfig enp2s0 up
   service network-manager restart
   ```

   make it executable, and subsequently
3. Create a launcher:

   ```bsh
   [Desktop Entry]
   Exec=gksu /path/to/script.sh
   Type=Application
   Name=Update
   Terminal=true
   ```

   Save it as `update.desktop`. *Also make this file executable* and place it somewhere to double click.

   Now when you double click the icon, you will be prompted for your password, and the script will be executed in your terminal.

   **OR**

   save the `.desktop`file in `~/.local/share/applications` to make it available in Dash (no need to make it executable then). Log out and back in to show it in Dash.

#### Notes

1. `gksu` does not notify you in case of occuring errors, hence the

   ```
   Terminal=true
   ```

   which will make the script execute in a terminal window.
2. Inside the script, we do not use the `sudo` in front of each command, since we run the script with `sudo`.
3. You can "pimp" your `.desktop` file with an icon, by adding a line:

   ```
   Icon=/path/to/icon.png
   ```

   more on `.desktop` files and their options [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/ar01s05.html).

Comment: `gksu /path/to/script.sh`  would be sufficient.

Comment: Of course! edited. Thanks! Initially, I had a more complicated command in mind...

Answer (score 0):

You are rebuilding the driver each and every time, which is unnecessary. What I see here is that your main issue is with  `rt5390sta` module - it is not loaded automatically on boot.

What you need to do is this:

1. Open `/etc/modules` file. Please note that the file will require root permissions to edit, so use `gksu gedit` to open graphical editor or `sudo nano` to open command-line editor in terminal.
2. Add `rt5390sta` line to it.
3. Save and close. Reboot to test.

After that, upon each reboot the module will be loaded automatically and no need for repeating those steps again.As such, there's also no need for launcher,too.

Comment: If the update includes a newer kernel version; that is, linux-image, after the requested reboot, `rt5390sta` will not exists in the newer kernel version and the `/etc/modules` method will be ineffective.

Comment: I opened the /etc/modules and this was already the text 

`# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

lp
rt5390sta

# Generated by sensors-detect on Thu Sep  4 09:16:43 2014
# Chip drivers
coretemp`

Comment: @makkekkazzo OK, thanks.And I'll try to work on a solution for what chili555 mentioned in his comment.   Should be pretty easy to achieve. Please remind me in a few days in case i forget

Comment: Ehi Serg, thanks for the help, I wanted to let you know that now the problem has to do quiet surely only with restarting and not only with update, bacause I create the launcher, I restarted (withoute any update) and the network wasn't there. thanks again