# Every time I restart the laptop the Wifi is off

Tags: networking, wireless, ralink

as said in the title everytime I restart my computer the Wifi-Network is off and I have to give the following commands to make it start again:

```
cd /home/makkekkazzo/2011_1007_RT5390_RT5392_Linux_STA_V2.5.0.3_DPO/
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt5390sta
sudo ifconfig enp2s0 up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

At the beginning it was a problem only with the updates and for this reason I made a launcher [with the help of this community](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868610/how-to-make-a-launcher-for-activate-wifi). But now the problem comes everytime I restart the laptop and for this reason I was thinking if there is a simpler and ultimate option. I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the Wifi-Card is a Ralink RT5390.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try to run `sudo depmod -a && sudo update-initramfs -u` after you `modprobe` the module.

Comment: As a temporary workaround, you can execute those commands automatically at boot using an init.d script.

Comment: Ehi Pilot6 unfortunately your suggestion didn't worked. I'll try with the init.d script. Thanks for the help